# MFMailComposeViewController reacting to sent emails based on recipient

Tags: ios, email, delegates, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have a button that will allow a user to send an email to a support address. There is also the option to use an email to share content with other users.

In the latter case, the fact that user has shared via email is tracked for statistical analysis.

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {

if (result == MFMailComposeResultSent){
    [[TrackingHelper sharedTracker] trackEvent:@"Product" action:@"SharedViaEmail" label:self.product.name];

}

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

}

Since this will be called both when the user shares via email and when the user sends a support email, I was wondering if there was a way to differentiate between the two in the delegate? the MFMailComposeResult is not useful as it only returns wether it succeeded or not. I was hoping to make a determination by retrieving the recipients of the sent mail and matching it to the support address, but as far as I know there is no way to do this.

Does anyone know if there is a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I usually do it was to define a variable to track which option was activated.

When "support email" is selected, set a flag `isSupportEmail = YES`
else `NO`.

Then, in mailComposeController,

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error 
{
    if (result == MFMailComposeResultSent)
    {
        if(isSupportEmail)
            [[TrackingHelper sharedTracker] trackEvent:@"Support" action:@"SupportViaEmail" label:self.product.name];
        else
            [[TrackingHelper sharedTracker] trackEvent:@"Product" action:@"SharedViaEmail" label:self.product.name];
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: It'd be nice if there were a way to pull some more useful information in the delegate after sending/saving/discarding and email but this will suffice. Thanks!